# Alternative to CharacterController

Tags: unity, collider, character-controller

I am really enjoying the use of charactercontroller, but it being limited by a y-axis aligned collider is a real annoying limitation when I am using a 'character' with a very different shape (like a car).

**Is there an available alternative with roughly the same interface that will allow the use of an arbitrary collider?** Even just a box collider would be great.
Most important features to carry over are of course collision and edge sliding.

Comment: I'm not aware of a similar alternative that is built into Unity. There are car controllers on the Asset Store, and I think Unity had one in the Standard Assets package, though Standard Assets is no longer supported in new versions of Unity.

Comment: @Kevin I don't necessarily need a built-in. A link to a similar build is fine. A 'car controller' will probably implement physics which is not what I am after though.

Comment: Questions about what tool to use are outside the scope of this Stack Exchange site, as they are subjective. We can answer questions about features built into the engine, but when the question turns into "what third-party library or asset store package can do what I want" it becomes too broad. You might try a web search for libraries/packages that meet your needs.

Comment: @Kevin Fair. I'd forgotten about that rule. I thought this may be on the edge of a code question.